# Extracting all cpio files in a directory

Tags: cpio

I'm using ssh to connect to a server which has a directory full of cpio files.
I need to extract all the files in the directory, so I tried to write in the terminal:

```
cpio -ivd
```

But when I press enter nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you read the man page?

Comment: there is no magic command that will extract all cpio in one pass like, e.g there is no foo option that do  `cpio -foo f1.cpio f2.cpio ... fn.cpio` and all file are extracted. You'll have to loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the cpio file to the standard input to extract it:
`cpio -idv < file.cpio`

To loop over the files, e.g. in Bash, do:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in *.cpio; do
    cpio -idv < "$filename"
done
```

The man page deals with this quite extensively:
https://linux.die.net/man/1/cpio

Comment: Thanks, but I need to extract all the files. can I do it in one command? I looked at the main page but didn't find a way to do it for all the files in the directory

Comment: Edited my answer.